# Android: class NOT FOUND in Eclipse-built external jar but IS FOUND in Netbeans-built one

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans, jar, external

This is a follow-up to this question: ["android can't find class from external jar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231059/android-cant-find-class-from-external-jar)

I have an Android project in Eclipse that uses an external JAR. The JAR is extremely simple: it contains a "toy" class that computes a square of a number and returns the result as a String.

**BAD**: If I create the JAR in **Eclipse** by creating a regular Java project with the class, then exporting it into a jar file, and finally adding this JAR to the build path of the Android project, I get a run time exception that this class cannot be found.

**GOOD**: If I create the JAR in **Netbeans** and add that JAR to the build path (in Eclipse), all works well.

I actually unzipped both jars to compare contents. It appears that the difference is in .class files but they are not human readable so I can't get any further.

***So my q is this***: what can I change in the Eclipse export to make the external jar "good"? What is NB doing right that Eclipse is doing wrong? Or do I simply resort to building all my external JARs in NB?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `javap` output for the class files?

Answer (score 6):

In the "Order and Export" tab of your Build Path screen, check the box for the missing jar

Comment: Check the box and make sure you move the jar 'Up' and place it above your actual source folder where you used the imported library's functionality. Thanks a bunch Kuffs, I've been banging my head for this solution for some hours now.

Comment: You saved my life. Two days and various Eclipse reinstallations after, the problem was in the library check and the library order...

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is linked to the ADT 17, the easiest workaround is to create a directory libs in your project and copy your jar into it. see [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490)