# Why do I get a NoClassDefFoundError on Android after adding a JAR via Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to include ZXing in my Android application.

As ZXing only supplies java source code, I created the jar file from it myself.

Next I added the JAR via dragging it to the libs folder of my Android project in Eclipse.

The project explorer looks like [this](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/853/unbenanntuyo.png)

The build path looks like [this](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/7205/unbenannt2uj.png)

In my own code I try to instantiate a class from that JAR:

```
IntentIntegratorV30 integrator = new IntentIntegratorV30(this);
```

No Errors at compile time.

But I get the following error at runtime on a real device:

```
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorV30
```

The complete LogCat is:

```
06-09 21:06:32.010: I/ApplicationPackageManager(1656): cscCountry is not German : XEO
06-09 21:06:32.010: I/dalvikvm(1656): Could not find method com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorV30.parseActivityResult, referenced from method de.fzi.guideme.fragments.scanner.ScannerFragment.onActivityResult
06-09 21:06:32.010: W/dalvikvm(1656): VFY: unable to resolve static method 181: Lcom/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegratorV30;.parseActivityResult (IILandroid/content/Intent;)Lcom/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult;
06-09 21:06:32.010: D/dalvikvm(1656): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
06-09 21:06:32.020: E/dalvikvm(1656): Could not find class 'com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorV30', referenced from method de.fzi.guideme.fragments.scanner.ScannerFragment.onCreateView
06-09 21:06:32.020: W/dalvikvm(1656): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 67 (Lcom/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegratorV30;) in Lde/fzi/guideme/fragments/scanner/ScannerFragment;
06-09 21:06:32.020: D/dalvikvm(1656): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002d
06-09 21:06:32.020: I/GuideMe(1656): Fragment: class de.fzi.guideme.fragments.scanner.ScannerFragment, manual: null, function: null, step: null
06-09 21:06:32.040: D/AndroidRuntime(1656): Shutting down VM
06-09 21:06:32.040: W/dalvikvm(1656): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401d2760)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegratorV30
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at de.fzi.guideme.fragments.scanner.ScannerFragment.onCreateView(ScannerFragment.java:47)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:735)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:926)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:909)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1584)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4377)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1724)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
06-09 21:06:32.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use Eclipse 3.7.2 with Android SDK Tools Rev. 19 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 3.1.

It looks like the JAR is not beeing included into the APK file. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Edit: Answering my own question (as a result of the discussion in the comments). The JAR I tried to include must be erroneous somehow. Building JARs correctly will be discussed elsewhere.

Comment: Are you compiling in debug mode (normal) or are you exporting a signed APK and using that? If the latter, ProGuard might somehow be messing things up, though that seems unlikely. Your configuration all seems fine. Here is a link to a sample project that uses that same JAR and works fine: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing

Comment: I am not completely shure about debug mode and signing. Where can I check that? I have not set the Debuggable option in the AndroidManifest.xml though.

Comment: If you don't know, you're building in debug mode -- building in production mode takes a few extra steps that you won't be able to miss... :-)

Comment: Ok, so ProGuard messing up somehow should not be the cause, I guess. I just downloaded the sample code you linked to and that compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: OK, so now you need to determine what is different between the two project setups. Or, perhaps grab the ZXing JAR out of my project and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm making progress. My project works with your JAR. But yours does not with my JAR. So I must have done something wrong building the JAR. The easy way would be to use your JAR now. But I'd like to use the IntentIntegratorV30 class that uses fragments and I'd also like to understand how to build the JAR correctly. So I'll explain how I create the JAR. Maybe there's an obvious error: I create a new Java Project. Add the .java files to the src directory. Adjust the package names. Right click on project "Export.../Java/Jar File" and go through the wizard.

Comment: You'd have to ask the ZXing folks how to properly create their JAR from Eclipse. I just used `ant`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help so far. At least I have got my code running now. :)

Answer (score 5):

This was killing me yesterday. I also had no errors building, but errors running. I think it has something to do with the way Android SDK compiles the build path. I finally repeated these steps and stopped getting the error:

1. Create a folder in the root of your Android project called libs.

   Add the jar to that folder.

   Right-click the jar and click to add to build path.

   Clean your project.

   Build project.

   Run.

via [android can't find class from external jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231059/android-cant-find-class-from-external-jar)

Comment: These instructions have been out of date since the R17 version of the ADT plugin for Eclipse, which is a couple of months old at this point.

Comment: I already did steps 1 and 2. When trying step 3 it says: "Error while adding a library. Reason: Could not write file: C:\Development\Workspace\GuideMe\.classpath." I guess, this is due to Android managing the build path itself now. Somehow...

Comment: No that's probably permissions. I had no problem adding it (on Mac OS).

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom: It is automatically added to your build path simply by having it in `libs/`.

Answer (score 2):

right click at your project >properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export->check the ZXing.jar

then clean the project and build it again

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio doesn't do a proper clean & build.

You have to follow Anna Billstrom's instructions, with the following caveat:

- Open your command line.
- Navigate to your project root.
- Execute `./gradle clean`
- Go back to Android Studio and run/debug your project.
- ?
- Profit.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error too.

It turns out that I was exporting the jar from an external project. However, as Eclipse did not know that I was going to use it for my Android project, it automatically set the compiler level to 1.7.

Android supports only 1.6, so the solution was, in the library project, before exporting:

Right click, `Properties` -> `Java compiler` -> `Compiler compilance level` -> 1.6