# eclipse can't import library inner class for android application

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, import, libraries

I've added a library to my android project by putting .jar file into /libs folder and by adding Project->Properties->Android->Add. The problem is that I can't import one static public inner class. Eclipse just shows me such type of errors:

```
GraphViewSeriesStyle cannot be resolved to a type
The import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries.GraphViewSeriesStyle cannot be resolved
```

I've tried all of these methods to fix it, but the didn't help:

[Gson NoClassDefFoundError after ADT and SDK Tools update to v17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17)

[Why do I get a NoClassDefFoundError on Android after adding a JAR via Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964024/why-do-i-get-a-noclassdeffounderror-on-android-after-adding-a-jar-via-eclipse)

[android can't find class from external jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231059/android-cant-find-class-from-external-jar)

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: which version is your ADT?

Comment: I've updated ADT to 17 version and Android SDK Tools to 22.

Comment: "Android SDK Build-tools" form sdk manager is set to 17?

Comment: yes, android sdk build-tools is set to 17

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17).
It helped me once, when I just updated ADT to version 17.

Comment: tried this, but still didn't help me. But after I put the .jar in /libs folder and then adding it ("add JAR" button), I see the library is in Android Private Libraries folder, not in Android Dependencies.

Comment: please describe briefly what's behind the link as it might go down in future